# Is it possible to pass a Future<String> Function as child path of a RTDB?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a mini app in flutter and i want to pass a string method as a child path of RTDB but doesn't work because my snapshot is empty. Is it possible to do so as like in my present code?:

```
import 'package:carrier_info/carrier_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/Material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    country();
  }

  static Future<String?> country() async {
    var info = await CarrierInfo.isoCountryCode;
    return ('"$info"');
  }

  final DatabaseReference dbRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(country().toString());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Gallery"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: dbRef.once(),
          builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.snapshot.value == null) {
              return const Center(child: Text("No data"));
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `dbRef` depends on a value that is asynchronously loaded, `dbRef` itself also has to be calculated asynchronously. And since you can't mark a variable/field as `async`, you will have to return the DB reference from a function and call that in an *additional* `FutureBuilder`.

So:

```
static Future<String?> country() async {
  var info = await CarrierInfo.isoCountryCode;
  return info;
}
Future<DatabaseReference> getDBRef() async {
  return FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(country().toString());
}
```

And then:

```
body: FutureBuilder(
  future: getDBRef(),
  builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: snapshot.data!.once(),
        builder: ...
      )
    }
    ...
```

---

You can also have that new function return the `Future` from `once`, so you won't need a nested `FutureBuilder`:

```
Future<DatabaseEvent> getData() async {
  var pays = await country();
  var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child(pays.toString());
  return ref.once();
}
```

And then:

```
body: FutureBuilder(
  future: getData(),
  builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    ...
```

Comment: First of all Thank you very much Sir for your help. I tested your solutions but both of them are throwing errors: For the first solution it says:Class 'Future<DatabaseReference>' has no instance getter 'snapshot'.Receiver: Instance of 'Future<DatabasReference>'
Tried calling: snapshot. For the second solution it says : A value of type 'Future<DatabaseEvent>' can't be returned from the method 'getData' because it has a return type of 'Future<DataSnapshot>.Replace  the return type with Future<Future<DatabaseEvent>> and when i do that it throw an error same as before(solution one)!. please help!

Comment: I fixed the return type in the second snippet.